# Javascript- How to disable a html button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to disable a  html button  on JavaScript `onclick` event ? I am using  a `input type="button"`

```
<input type="button" class="standardbutton" value="Password Reset" id="mybutton" onclick=" passwordReset()"/>
```

Since I am not using jquery or any framework for the UI, how to disable it?

I tried to set `disabled = true`, but it didn't work.

**For example:**

```
 document.getElementById("mybutton").disabled = true;
```

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question, so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be nice as well

Comment: add relevant code to understand problem

Comment: juqery can help you to do it very quickly

Comment: $('#mybutton').attr('disabled', 'true');

Comment: @willie The user specifically stated that he is not using Jquery

Comment: @willie `document.querySelector('#mybutton').disabled = true` how is that any more slower or complicated than fetchnig jQuery just to use its `attr()`?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the console? It is possible you are trying to disable the button at the time the DOM has not been fully built yet (so JavaScript can't see the element). The code itself is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set disabled = true in javascript function

```
     <input type="button" class="standardbutton" value="Password Reset" id="mybutton" onclick=" passwordReset()"/>
```

In JS

```
function passwordReset(){
  document.getElementById("mybutton").disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me

```js
function disableBtn1(){
  document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Btn 1"/>
<button id="btn2" onclick="disableBtn1();"> btn 2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `disabled=true` should work, you may have an error somewhere else :

```js
function toggle_disable() {
  var button = document.getElementById("test");

  if (button.disabled) {
    button.disabled = false;
  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="test" value="I'm a button"/>

<input type="button" id="toggle" onclick="toggle_disable()" value="&lt;= Disable it !"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="button">My Button</button>

<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="disable()">Click</button>

<script>
  function disable() {
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```